Order 2 branch cut and different sheet structures on Riemann surfaces
I am trying to understand some simple branch structures of Riemann surfaces with order 2 ramification / branch points. Let's talk about surfaces in $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ cut out by a polynomial $P(y,z)$. I will denote the projection map by $\pi: \Sigma \to \mathbb{C}$. I am interested in placing order two branch points at a finite set of points $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_N$ in $\mathbb{C}$, we could, for concreteness, think of these as the positive integers up to $N$.
One example could be the analytic continuation of:
$$
y(z) = \sqrt{(z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2)\ldots (z-\alpha_N)}
$$
This defines a simple degree $2$ curve $P(y,z) = y^2 - (z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2)\ldots (z-\alpha_N)$. The sheet structure is the first sketch in the attached image.
Another example could be the analytic continuation of:
$$
y(z) = \sqrt{z-\alpha_1} + \sqrt{z-\alpha_2} + \ldots + \sqrt{z-\alpha_N}
$$
This has a more complicated sheet structure. It is not too hard to see that $P$ is now degree $2^N$, an example is sketched in the 3rd picture.
My question is simple, does there exist a degree $N$ polynomial that interpolates between these two sheet structures. I.e. I would like to write down a surface $\Sigma$ defined by a $P(y,z)$ whose sheet structure under $\pi$ looks like the image in picture 2.
One can obtain some constraints by studying the discriminant and the valency of the ramification points but I haven't been able to satisfy these. Namely the first case has discriminant proportional to the product of $(z-\alpha_i)$ and the second case proportional to the product of $(z-\alpha_i)^N$ with repeated roots. We would like a degree $N$ polynomial with a discriminant proportional to the product of simple factors $(z-\alpha_i)$.


By interpolate, are you seeking a polynomial in three variables, perhaps $P(t, y, z)$ such that $P(0, y, z)$ and $P(1, y, z)$ have the two types of branch behavior?

Thanks for your comment! No, that’s actually my poor choice of language. Such a polynomial would be fun, but actually I just want a polynomial in 2 variables like the other two examples. I said interpolate because I want some O(N) growth behaviour of the sheets in between the O(1) and O(2^N) examples I gave!
